# Date Format Issues

Tags: javascript, date

So I have this date returned from an API:

`"2014-08-07T00:00Z"`

And the results from `new Date("2014-08-07T00:00Z")` equal `Wed Aug 06 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` and .getDay() on that date gives me 3.

Why is it going from August 7th, to 6th, and the getDay returns 3?

Basically I'm trying to turn the API return date into english.

```
days[d.getDay()]+", "+months[d.getMonth()]+" "+getOrdinal(d.getDay())+" "+formatAMPM(d)
```

(aka "Wednesday, August 3rd 8:00 pm")

```
console.log(d,data[i].startDate, d.getDay());
//yields
// Wed Aug 06 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) "2014-08-07T00:00Z" 3
```

`days` is just an array of text days, as is `months`, `getOrdinal` is a function that gives the text `st` or `nd` or `rd` on the day, and `formatAMPM` is pretty obvious.

Comment: You could just use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you need sane date handling. Js standard Date is flunky.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't feel like a whole library is required for converting a date into a string version

Comment: @SterlingArcher It may not seem so at first, but consider timezones (and their occasional updates) and localization, plus the reverse case (turning localized dates back into API format). Moment is probably worth pulling in, or will be soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.getDay()` returns the day of the week. I think you'd expect `.getDate()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

That's why you're seeing that it is a Wednesday.

The result for me of `new Date("2014-08-07T00:00Z")` is `Wed Aug 06 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)`. This is because dates are converted to your local timezone when constructed

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I just realized I wanted getDate not getDay... stupid mistake.

Comment: well said, as it is converted to local time so the 7 become 6. Thumps up

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any problem here. 
Your date is 2014-08-07T00:00Z, with Z meaning Zulu Time Zone (equivalent to UTC), and using `new Date()` on it will convert to you local time, here GMT-4, that is why you are getting 4 hours difference. 
And For the "3", the getDay() method returns the day of the week, wednesday in your case.

Comment: You too well said, as it is converted to local time so the 7 become 6. +1